# Old story about an assassin squad sent to kill a man who stopped war

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story is told from the point of view of a member of a squad of soldiers sent to infiltrate a dome of some kind that belongs to an immortal man who stopped all countries from fighting wars.

The immortal constructed the dome and would fire missiles at any country that launched an attack of an kind.

> The view point character is a member of the 30th squad sent to kill the immortal. They infiltrate the dome but end up in a death trap maze where each member dies except him. He survives and confronts the immortal who is actually a member of the 10th squad sent to kill the immortal. The immortal did exist but at some point a squad killed him. Instead of letting all the countries restart war a single member of the squad decided to continue the anti war campaign.

All numbers are approximate.

Ring any bells for anyone?

Comment: Sorry to complain but the third paragraph is a pretty big spoiler... could you add a spoiler tag? All the info on formatting is here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: They stopped wars by firing missiles at countries? What a clever idea. Maybe we should try that in real life.

Comment: Same as [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76751/short-story-from-the-80s-about-a-strike-team-going-through-some-tunnels-with-de)?

Comment: Actually that does sound like the story.

Comment: Question: was the final soldier to make it then chained so he couldn't abandon his post? This rings a faint bell