# Short story from the 80's about a strike team going through some tunnels with deadly traps

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to recall a short science fiction story, I think from the 80's.

It involved a military strike team, going through some tunnels/maze with deadly traps in each section which kill off various members of the team.

The very last guy arrives and talks to the person in the bunker who informs him he is his  successor. I think they call this guy the, "Great Satan(?)". He basically suppresses the excessive military in the world, firing missiles if anyone steps out of line, aka, the sole superpower.

I was originally thinking it might be a John Varley story but it's not him.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack exchange :) .. i suggest you take the tour and go on the help center ;) .. nice question but be extra carefull on the way you say your question "..." no you better put "," and be sure to put a point at the end of a sentence and start a new one with a capital letter in answers and questions especially :D

Comment: I remember a sort of similar story, I think by Harlan Ellison, that involved a strike team trying to make their way to a heavily fortified location, but the watcher was an AI.  They wanted to blind it, feeding it pre-recorded information on a loop that showed everything being okay, so that humanity could go back to warring again.  I don't remember the title.

Comment: @WillFeldman - Or Colossus:The Forbin Project, where a computer (basically the precursor to SKynet) takes over the world by threatening to nuke everyone.

Comment: I know I've seen this question here before... the kicker is the bit in the end where the last guy takes over the job of the guy in the center.

Comment: Same as [this one[(http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72665/old-story-about-an-assassin-squad-sent-to-kill-a-man-who-stopped-war)?