# Story about a tyrant who was one of a series to unite the world

Tags: story-identification

I read this story sometime in the past twenty years. It was in an anthology but I don't remember the title. A tyrant rules the world and soldiers would assault his fortress. One soldier whose father had died assaulting it survives the assault. He kills the tyrant to find a list of names of men. He realizes that the tyrant is a series of men who realize the world is only united because there is a tyrant. He also finds that his father had been one of the men. I had this book the story was in but in my military career I misplaced it. Anyone have a clue what the title and author is?

Comment: Are there any science fiction or fantasy elements?

Comment: @Adamant If you're asking about the technological level of the society, yes, that could be helpful for identifying the story. Of course, the alternate-history aspect (a world state) is enough to make it on-topic.

Comment: Do you remember anything about the anthology? Was it a hardcover, trade paperback, mass market paperback? Published in America, Britain, Australia? Was it a best-of-the-year anthology, or a themed anthology (like military SF or political SF), or miscellaneous?

Comment: I'm almost certain there's an earlier question here about this story, but I don't remember if it received any answers...

Comment: Found it. Is it possibly the same as this? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72665/old-story-about-an-assassin-squad-sent-to-kill-a-man-who-stopped-war